# Need assistance with 4 Algebra Word Problems

Tags: word-problem

I'm currently struggling a bit here on these 4 math problems. Guidance and solutions are utmost appreciated:

A resort offers vacationers two diving adventure plans. Plan A gives 3 nights lodging and 5 dives. Plan B gives 5 nights lodging and 6 dives.

1) Let n be the number of dollars charged per night and let d be the number of dollars charged per dive. Write 2 expressions, one for the amount you would pay for plan A and the other for the amount you would pay for plan B.

- I asked my teacher for help on this, all the advice she gave was to make two equations so I set:

Amount for lodging = nx

Amount for dives = dy

2) Evaluate the expressions in #1 if lodging is \$125/night and dives are \$50/each. Show the setup.

What I got; not sure if it's right.

- Plan A = 125 x 3 + 50 x 5 = \$650
- Plan B = 125 x 5 + 50 x 6 = \$950

3) If lodging is increased to \$150 per night and dives are decreased to \$35 each, does the cost of either of the plans change? If the cost of a plan changes, does it increase or decrease and by what amount?

Tried this; however, i'm not sure if this is correct.

- Plan A = 150 x 3 + 35 x 5 = \$625
- Plan B = 150 x 5 + 35 x 6 = \$960

Plan A - by \$25 and Plan B + by \$10

4) The resort posts an offer in which plan A costs \$550 and plan B cost \$800. What prices are now being assumed per night and per dive? Show the setup.

Once again, thank you!

Comment: Your question will probably be closed unless you edit it to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. And please fix the formatting. The dollar signs tell the system that you are starting to write mathematics rather than text. Put a backslash \ in front of the dollar signs.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up pal

Comment: These look right to me (quick read). You should say "Let $x$ be the number of nights and $y$ the number of days. For the last unanswered question: there is an algebraic method (google  _simultaneous linear equations_ ) but you could solve it by guess-and-check. When you do, you can post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

**4)** If we use the definitions in 1) the two equations are

$3n+5d=550 \quad \quad I$

$5n+6d=800 \quad \quad II$

This is a linear equation system with 2 variables and 2 equations. To solve a linear equation system there are 2 methods to solve them: *Method of Substitution* and *Method of Elemination* .

I solve the system by using the method of substitution. Solving one equation for one variable. I solve the second equation for $n$

$5n+6d=800$

$5n=800-6d$

*Dividing both sides of the equation by 5*

$n=160-\frac65 d$

Now we take the expression for $n$ and insert it into the other (first) equation.

$3\cdot (160-\frac65 d) +5d=550$

*Multiplying out the brackets*

$480-\frac{18}5d+5d=550$

$480-3.6d+5d=550$

$480+1.4d=550$

*Subtracting $480$ on both side of the equation*

$1.4d=70$

$d=50$

To get the value of n we can use one of the two equations, $I$ or $II$. I use the first one. You can use the second equation and see if you´ll get the same value for $n$.

$3n+5\cdot 50=550$

$3n+250=550$

$3n=300$

$n=100$